# Is there a way by which I can use icons inside table instead of showing data

Tags: html, angular, font-awesome

I have an array of vegetables =

```
[
  {"day":"sunday", "tomatos": 5, "potatos": 3, "okra": 3, "total" : 11},
  {"day":"monday", "tomatos": 0, "potatos": 2, "okra": 1, "total" : 3},
  {"day":"tuesday", "tomatos": 0, "potatos": 0, "okra": 0, "total" : 0}
]
```

I want to display it in a table using angular (*ngFor) as shown below with a cross for 0 values and tick for non zero along with the value.

My current code for table:-

```
<table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>days</th>
          <th>tomatos</th>
           <th>potatos</th>  
           <th>okra</th>
            <th>total</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let data of vegetables">
           <td>{{data.days}}</td>
          <td>{{data.tomatos}}</td>
          <td>{{data.potatos}} </td>
          <td>{{data.total}} </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
```

Way I want it to display:-

```
                   days          tomatos          potatos       okra      total  
                   sunday         (Tick)5          (Tick)3      (Tick)3   (Tick)11
                   monday           X              (Tick)2      (Tick)1   (Tick)3
                   tuesday          X                 X            X         X
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, but why not just put an `<img>` within your `<td>`? I.E. `<td><img src='path/to/img/ticks_{{data.tomatos}}.png'></td>`

Comment: image is not looking good I want to use font icons

Comment: Then the same concept applies, you'll just need to set-up some CSS to the work. `<td><i class='ticks_{{data.tomatos}}'></i></td>`

Comment: Or if you want to be really cool, use attributes: `<td><i data-value='{{data.tomatos}}'></i></td>` Then you can do something like `[data-value]{ ... } [data-value="1"] { ... }  [data-value="2"] { ... }   [data-value="3"] { ... }` etc., etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is have a if/else in your table data template for when the value is 0, and when it isn't:

```
<td>
    <div *ngIf="data.tomatoes === 0; then showCross else showTick"></div>

    <ng-template #showCross>
        <i class="icon-cross-class"></i>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template #showTick>
        <i class="icon-tick-class"></i>{{ data.tomatoes }}
    </ng-template>
</td>
```